# Linear vs Quadratic integer programming on the example spread vs variance

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

I consider the following two instances of the same problem, computing the spread as the difference of the highest and lowest occurrence of something in a set. Further, I compute the variance of the elements in the set.

In my optimisation problems, I have several sets that are interconnected in differently. I try to determine the minimal spread/variance by either using MILPs or QILPs (because the variance includes a squaring operation).

A "spread" MILP could look something like this:
$$\begin{align}
\text{minimize} \quad & \sum_{v\in V}y_\max(v) - y_\min(v) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \sum_{w\in W} x(v,w) \le y_\max(v) \quad \forall v\in V \\
& \sum_{w\in W} x(v,w) \ge y_\min(v) \quad \forall v\in V\\
& \text{...further problem related constraints...}\\
& y_\min(v),y_\max(v) \in\mathbb{N}, x(v,w)\in{0,1} \quad \forall v \in V, w\in W
\end{align}$$

How to explain why I experience in all my cases that the QILP, even for large problem instances, is faster than its considered approximation.

Assumptions:

1. Problem instances are still too small
2. Additional constraints and variables make the MILP harder to compute